# Turn on Adb without usb

Tags: android, command, adb, remote-debugging

I want to debug my apps in my android rooted device. How can i connect adb without USB (not even once) or without any third party apps.

```
su
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

Above command works in android device terminal and also used same commend in my code, worked in lollipop.
But not in below lollipop, (Super user permission granted.)

Below code works in lollipop,

```
 List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<String>();
          cmdList = loadCmdList();


     for (int i = 0; i < cmdList.size(); i++)
            {
                String cmd = cmdList.get(i);
                Log.d(TAG, "cmd   >>>" + cmd);

                Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            }


              public  List<String> loadCmdList()
        {
            List<String> cmdList=new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                cmdList.add("adb shell su");
                // cmdList.add("su");
                cmdList.add("setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555");
                cmdList.add("stop adbd");
                cmdList.add("start adbd");
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"Exception    >>>"+ Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
            return  cmdList;
            }
```

But not in below lollipop.

Comment: So you want to connect your device without a USB cable?

Comment: @ Roderick Lord , Yes you are correct. I can achieve the same using terminal,  But I want to do same problematically. Even if I integrate  same in  my code it is working fine in lollipop. But not below versions.

Comment: Are you using Wi-Fi to connect to ADB?

Comment: @ Roderick Lord,  I am using Ethernet (Android Box), I am ok  if it is Wifi . But don't want to use any other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYcaG1MDcBU. There is also an application that allows you connect to ADB via Wi-Fi: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en. XDA developers also has the ADB Tools as well if you want a look: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-adb-tools-t2954734. There are many other more ways as well.

Google also has official documentation on how to connect:

1. Connect device and your computer with ADB to a common Wi-Fi network accessible to both.
2. Connect your device to the computer with a USB cable.
3. Set the target device to listen for a TCP/IP connection on port 5555.

   `$ adb tcpip 5555`
4. Disconnect the USB cable.
5. Find the IP address of your device.
6. Connect to the device with your IP address

   `$ adb connect device_ip_address`
7. Confirm your connection to the target device:

   `$ adb devices
   List of devices attached
   device_ip_address:5555 device`

More can be found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: I don't want to use any apps. Above commands works fine in terminal and also in lollipop. I want to achieve same in below versions of android.

Comment: I don't want to connect to USB at all. Without usb above code works fine in lollipop. I need to achieve same in below lollipop versions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any other way.

Comment: The question literally says connect "without a USB".

Answer (score 0):

Connect ADB device to pc.

1) move to path c:user/your_pc_name/android-sdk/sdk/platform-tool

2) adb devices
    list of devices
        your device name

3) adb tcpip 5555
    restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

4)check your mobile ip address
    setings>about phone>status

5) adb connect your ip address:5555
    ex: 192.168.1.111:5555

Comment: Connect ADB device to PC:   I don't want to use USB or third party apps at all to connect ADB. I want to start ADB in device with out usb.

Comment: it is not possible without third party apps and usb.

Comment: No it is possible. Above code works in lollipop. But not in below versions.

Comment: How to turn this off after I have done my work for that day?